# I came across plagiarism. Whom should I inform if at all?

Tags: plagiarism, books, publishers

I have been reading a sample PDF of a book by a professor at a research university published in 2007 on the publisher’s website. For some reason the book’s title was not included in the PDF’s footer (as it should be) so I had to google a passage from the book with the hope that Google Books would provide me with the title. I was quite surprised when it provided me with two titles.

There was a second book by a completely different author (an engineer with a PhD who works in the industry) published in 2015. Not only was the passage there but the whole paragraph (possibly more) verbatim. And even though the second book had tons of references, the first book wasn’t among them.

Should I let someone know about it? If yes, whom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest contacting the original author (A1) to let them know about the (probable) plagiarism, rather than directly contacting the second author/publisher (A2/P2).  This way:

- At the point where you get in touch with a stranger, you are not accusing them of anything, so communication is much less loaded/constrained.
- If A1 tells you they have authorised the re-use, then you know it’s OK; whereas if you contact A2/P2 and they say it was authorised, it’s hard to be sure you can trust them (since their ethics are already in question).
- If the re-use is indeed not authorised, then A1 is the person with the best legal and moral authority to contact the publishers P2 and make this allegation.

Answer (score 32):

Not to copy and paste my answer from another question, but...

You should contact the editor/publisher of the book which plagiarized (book 2), present your claims, and be prepared to submit evidence. If there's no response, contact the editor/publisher of the original book (book 1) - they may be able to use legal means to force the matter.

Comment: What are your reasons for suggesting contacting the second publisher directly, rather the original author/publisher?  In [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/67957/1277) I suggest the opposite order; but it would be useful to hear the potential advantages of both options.

Comment: @PLL: Chiefly because it's more direct. The problem does not lie with the original author/publisher - they've done nothing wrong. Contacting the second publisher directly addresses the core issue - an author *they* published has plagiarized, and it's up to them to (1) stop publishing the book, and (2) notify the original publisher/author about what happened. I'm making the assumption that this publisher will do the right thing, of course - their reputation is at stake. Should they fail to do so, however, you can then fall back to the original publisher/author.

Comment: @tonysdg Assuming that OP is a 3rd party for this, I don't see a reason for disclosing oneself, and coming across as an accuser. Also, original publisher is at loss. They should know it immediately, and it's up to them whether or not to act upon it. This seems like a perfectly reasonable approach to me. And it's less work, going straight to the party in whose interest is to act. Your appears as a perfect course of action for some who got plagiarised.

Comment: @luk: Ultimately, I don't personally think there are any problems with contacting the original author/publisher first - the end result of presenting your claims and submitting evidence does not change. That said, how does that approach prevent oneself coming across as an accuser? Regardless of who you contact, you *are* essentially accusing someone of plagiarism (and possibly rightly so). All that changes is who you are making your accusations to - the publisher of the plagiarized work, or the publisher of the plagiarizing work.

Comment: By analogy, if you spot somebody stealing a car you *could* confront them (which is most direct of all), or you *could* inform the owner of the car (who has the incentive and support of the legal system to do something about it). Or you could contact the police. But in the real case of plagiarism there is no certain equivalent of the police: the plagiariser's publisher *might* act in the role of the police, or might act in the role of the thief, you don't know for sure. If you have confidence in the publisher, though, then they're a reasonable bet to do something about it, hence this answer.

Answer (score 17):

Be aware that it's possible that the second author (A2) didn't plagiarize the first author (A1).  Both authors could have copied from an earlier source.

You mention that A2 has tons of references, perhaps the original source is listed among them.

Be careful not to slander anyone with your inquiries.

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be saying that it might be slanderous to claim "A2 plagiarized A1" in a situation where the truth is that A2 and A1 both plagiarized A0. If A2 really is a plagiarist, it's hard to see how accusing them of plagiarizing the wrong person could be slanderous.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I'm just saying "be careful".  Maybe A2 referenced A0 and OP didn't notice because they were just looking for a reference to A1's paper.  Maybe the paragraph was even copied from an old paper published by A2 20 years ago.

Comment: @James If you copy a passage word-for-word, that's still plagiarism, even if you reference the original source...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Not if you properly credit the source.  Also, you arguably can't plagiarize your own past work. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31199/is-it-inappropriate-for-an-author-to-copy-and-paste-from-his-her-original-paper?lq=1

Comment: Note that based on the OP's description I think it is likely that A2 plagiarized A1.  However, there is room for doubt.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the OP has no *proof* that the academic didn't give the industrialist permission to use the material. Since the OP only read "a sample" of the book, we don't even know if the industrialist *acknowledged* a general permission to reuse the academic's work in a part of the book which the OP didn't read.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft A lot of people confuse plagiarism with copyright infringement. Plagiarism is attribution failure; a cited quotation isn't plagiarism but can be infringement. The connection between the two is that sometimes plagiarism contributes to infringement when a license requires attribution or a defendant is trying to show clean hands for a fair use defense.

Comment: @alephzero What you say is true but that is not the argument being made in this answer. The argument being made in this answer is exactly that you shouldn't accuse A2 of plagiarizing A1 because they might actually be plagiarizing somebody else instead.

Comment: @DamianYerrick: There is a **huge** difference between "a cited quotation" and a word-for-word copy of a paragraph with no indication that it's a quotation, plus a citation to the source in the back of the book.  The latter is still plagiarism.

Comment: @James: you also need quotation marks around text you're quoting, and to say you're quoting it. And self-plagiarism is totally possible, as explained in this (uncontroversial to me) answer to the question you cite: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/31201/8966

Comment: You should send both publishers _the facts_ and not _your interpretation of the facts_. The facts are that Book 2 contains text identical to that in Book 1, and that you couldn't find a citation for Book 1 anywhere. It would be possible that both books correctly cited a passage from another Book 0, and the author of Book 2 didn't cite Book 1 because he or she never copied from or maybe not even read that book.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I'm not entirely sure whether the questioner is concerned about academic plagiarism or copyright infringement. The question is about books, and I have on many occasions encountered textbooks in which the inline citations are... let's say "scanty" rather than "completely absent". There seem to be contexts in which you can as a rule get away with just a bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to informing the editor/publisher of the book which was plagiarised, I might also be better to bring this to notify this to the original author of the plagiarised book too (if possible).