# I spotted a paper which has six pages worth of plagiarism: should I report it to the editor of the journal?

Tags: citations, paper-submission, plagiarism

I spotted a 2019 paper which literally copy-pastes paragraphs from a 2011 paper and doesn't cite them. The author (who is different than the 2011 paper's) claims that as their own research paper. Should I report this to the journal?

The paper has six pages of copied content. Out of 46, 6 pages are complete copy-paste.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you already know this, but make sure the following two facts are true before you report the paper.  1) This paper was published AFTER the other paper.  2) The two papers do not share a common author.

Comment: 1) Copied from a paper published in 2011. The paper which plagiarized in 2019. 2) Not the same author

Comment: @James A common author does not make plagiarism okay.

Comment: Even when it's the same author a copy-paste of substantial text is questionable. The text is usually copyright of the journal.  If there is "boiler plate" that an author wants to re-use, they should publish a review article and then cite that.

Comment: If it is so obvious that this is reprehensible behavior why ask? This question seems designed to elicit certain types of automatic responses.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - a common author makes it not plagiarism.

Comment: @Davor, that is not true. Self-plagirarism is still a thing, and is still a form of plagiarism. Even a blanket "This was previously published in ..." is pushing the limit when it is 6 pages long

Comment: @Davor https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2895/13240

Comment: For the discussion going on in the comments, see [Attitudes towards self-plagiarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2893/attitudes-towards-self-plagiarism). Opinions vary but many people oppose referring to such a mistake as (unqualified) plagiarism.

Comment: Call attention to the 2019 paper authors' academic institutions' departments of research integrity/academic conduct as well.

Answer (score 53):

Yes. Such a grave case of academic misconduct should have publicly visible consequences. Let the editor know; the journal should issue a retraction as the whole article can be deemed to be unreliable.

As retractions can take a long time, it would also be useful if you comment on the suspicion of plagiarism on [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/). (The authors could respond with a defense there if needed.)

Comment: Few questions:-  • Is the entire paper unreliable because of the following?  •The author has been cited and told his study(review paper) is noteworthy. Should the person who has cited be made aware ? •What exactly should I write to the editor?

Comment: @Hihwsjai I think the theory is that if he would copy 6 pages, he'd likely copy others, we just don't know where from yet. Everything is tainted by this obvious misconduct.

Comment: @Barmar Copy or *fabricate*. Once someone is confirmed to be dishonest in one way, we can't safely trust anything they write.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, draw it to relevant attention.

Not least because if its a mistake the authors should have a chance to fix it; if (more likely) it isn't then who knows what the implications will be, down the line, of dishonest papers. People could spend years of their life doing work, only to find its invalidated and wasted, because underlying material was unreliable. Or, you don't say what the field is, but real harm could arise in many cases. People getting hurt or at risk, due to faked or inappropriately copied material (do you know what a plagiatlrist - a dishonest academic writer -will do next?!). Businesses and products based on these in part,not knowing the authors are dishonest.

You may want to consider best ways to disclose - who to tell and how to best approach it. This falls under academic whistleblowing.

**But that's a different question.**

Should you make the publisher, or some other relevant academic/s aware, in some suitable way - absolutely. Even if at worst, its simply an anonymous post showing the 2 papers side by side so it's unmistakable, and a link sent to various places where it'll do good.

*(I don't necessarily know if that's the right way, but I use it to show that even if fearful of repercussions, there's a way. You need to ask how to disclose, too, but that as I said is a different question.....)*

Comment: Calling the plagiarism to the attention of the publisher as well as the editors is particularly appropriate.

Answer (score -5):

As others suggest, I would report this, but - depending on the circumstances, and if you want to help the author save face somewhat, you might contact them first. You wouldn't ask "Have you plagiarized this section from that paper?" But rather "I've been reading your paper X and believe that sections Y might be a verbatim quote from paper Z. Is this correct?" ... then depending on their answer you'll know how to report this to the publisher.

Comment: How can we help the author save face when he is stripping himself? 6 pages!!

Comment: @FailedScientist: 1. I said _if_. 2. But why would someone flaunt 6 copied pages? Maybe there's some misunderstanding. Or maybe not. I don't know.

Comment: @einpoklum Its probably a mistake but I think not. Because he claims he has cited everyone but the sentencing has itself been changed and the sentence makes a wrong claim. So I'm not sure in the plagiarism was intentional or a mistake.

Comment: @Hihwsjai: If you're not certain, it's probably better to ask first and accuse later rather than the other way around.

Comment: Oh yes I did ask. The whole article seems to be just copy pastes from other articles. I'm not sure so I'm not gonna report

Comment: @Hihwsjai: Mind that it’s the journal’s responsibility to hear all sides involved, correctly judge the case, and take appropriate action – not yours. You do not have to present irrefutable proof, just sufficient evidence to justify an investigation (by the journal). This certainly applies if a substantial part of the article is copy pasta. Contacting the author may even be counter-productive since it gives them a head start, which they may e.g. use to retract the paper for a less damning reason. At least, contacting the author is something that any responsible journal should do again anyway.

Answer (score -9):

In cases of academic misconduct where you are not personally involved, it's often better to go do something useful instead of filing complaints.

There's lots of plagiarized papers out there that nobody's going to read.  Limit your complaints to academic misconduct that involves you personally or has importance to research or safety.

Comment: I've never filed a complaint for plagiarism with a journal, but I image it would take the amount of time required to write one email and then possibly follow up replies once or twice. This to me does not seem to be a large investment of time

Comment: If you're not personally involved, you suggest not doing anything; but if you are personally involved you're biased and there are risks to you, so the same suggestion might be made. The result is that you should never bring this up.... not buying it. "There's lots of plagiarized papers out there that nobody's going to read. " <- Well, due to OP there may be one less.

Comment: @einpoklum "if you are personally involved you're biased and there are risks to you"  Not a valid reason not to address the problem.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: It doesn't seem more or less invalid than the reason you listed...

Comment: @einpoklum "because it's useful" is much more valid than "because you are biased."

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, "useful" can be malicious, such as spreading false information about where a fact was originated. If the paper in question is cited for a plagiarized section, then it becomes useful, but in the wrong way. Correcting that citing will be much harder than preventing it. "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure."

Comment: @computercarguy I cannot understand your comment at all.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, if you cited a plagiarized section of a paper, you are making that paper "useful", but you should have instead cited the original paper that was plagiarized. Trying to correct your cite after it's published is much harder than knowing not to cite a paper that's plagiarizing another. As for it being malicious, there's plenty of examples of "news" media that try to cite scientific/medical papers specifically to twist their meaning. If the author of this "news" simply doesn't cite their sources (as many don't), they are maliciously trying to become the source of a fact.

Answer (score -10):

I would also try to check if the 2 papers are both graduate student papers where the 2 authors were graduate students at the same time for the same advisor. There are some subjects where the first 6 pages is boilerplate as things are getting set up. If the advisor tells the 2nd student to copy the first 6 pages from the 1st student's paper, that is lazy but not exactly dishonest.

Comment: Scholarly dishonesty (plagiarism) is separate from intentional (personal) dishonesty. This type of "laziness" is still plagiarism and the same consequences apply, including the author gaining a reputation of untrustworthiness.

Comment: It depends on the subject. In science it is the results which are valued, specifically the new results. It is not the exact configuration of words to convey a basic idea which are important.

Comment: For example, in several mathematical papers on mean-field spin glasses, the first few pages are the definition of the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model, and the description of interpolation and Gaussian integration-by-parts. It is not really even lazy to cut-and-paste those sections, it is just smart.

Comment: Verbatim cutting-and-pasting without attribution is always plagiarism, even in mathematics, and even if it is "standard material". The SK model shouldn't need "a few pages" to describe, and even if it does, why not play safe by saying "the following standard details can be found in e.g. [name of source]"?

Comment: "In science it is the results which are valued, specifically the new results." There is some truth to this, but in the more pure-leaning areas of mathematics part of the new work is the new explanation. Authors who just recycle other people's insights as their own, without attribution, may rapidly get a bad reputation.

Comment: @Yemon-Choi The first however-many-pages of SK papers are not recycling other people's results as their own. They are definition of the Hamiltonian, notation/definition for the partition function and setup of interpolation. To somebody outside the field they could (maybe not?) be surprised to see that various papers have practically identical set-ups. It is the ideas after those initial pages that are important. [Hi hwsjai](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/151739/hi-hwsjai) did not disclose their subject paper or offending pages. In the types of papers I have described the intro is ok.